# UITextView providing incorrect caret rect

Tags: ios, uitextview

My UITextView delegate is logging the caret position using the following:

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    CGPoint cursorPosition = [textView caretRectForPosition:textView.selectedTextRange.start].origin;
    NSLog(@"cursor: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(cursorPosition));
}
```

But the reported position is always inaccurate. Specifically, it reports the *previous* cursor position - for example, if I click once inside the text view at position (x,y) then outside, then back inside at (x2,y2), on the second click the (x,y) coordinates are logged.

In fact, the selectedTextRange is the issue - the previous range is reported.

What am I missing? I don't see another delegate method I can use instead.

Answer (score 5):

Value of *selectedTextRange* will be older only as the editing has just began, it has not changed yet. As you are calculating the *cursorPostion* with selected text, old values will lead to old position. So we need to calculate the new position inside a different delegate which reports after the selection changes. You will get correct readings with below mentioned code. Hope it helps

```
-(void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView
{
    CGPoint cursorPosition = [textView caretRectForPosition:textView.selectedTextRange.start].origin;
    NSLog(@"cursor start: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(cursorPosition));
}
```

Comment: This is very surprising since the delegate method is *did*BeginEditing, not *will*BeginEditing. Do you have a source or any other info? I can't use the method you suggest since it will fire whenever the user changes the selection which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: No, i don't have any documentation reference to backup. My claim is purely based on the experimentation i did. But isn't it quite obvious that _didBegin_ actually just refer to the start of some edit process. If we try to draw the analogy with __UITextField__ _delegates_; _didBeginEditing_ didn't imply that content has been changed. Just my thoughts :)

Comment: This had me pulling my hair out for hours. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty gross but one solution is to introduce a short delay before reading calling the method:

```
UITextView *textView = note.object;

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.01 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    CGPoint cursorPosition = [textView caretRectForPosition:textView.selectedTextRange.start].origin;
    NSLog(@"cursor: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(cursorPosition));
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Using the delay worked for me too! I don't know if there's any other solution, since `textViewDidBeginEditing` is the last method that gets called after textView begins editing. @Gandalf solution is good too, but it only gets called if the selection is different from the previous selection.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found another solution to this.

You can use the `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` to get the current selectedTextRange, and not the previous selectedTextRange. I hope it helps!

Comment: when `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` is received, it is too late to start animation. But yes, at this point caret position is reported correctly.

Comment: @deville Yes, I prefer the delay too since it gives the correct caret rect right away. But you can see in Apple's Notes app that they use `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`(they are also using UIScrollView's auto scroll which is quiet a mess), so I take it that Apple meant `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` to get the caret rect and that getting incorrect caret rect in `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` is not a bug, although I think they should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but with `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`. Adding a small delay helped in my case:

```
func keyboardWillAppear(notification: NSNotification!) {
    dispatch_after_delay(0.01) {            
        if textView.selectedTextRange {
             // at this point range is correct 
        }
    }
}

func dispatch_after_delay(delay:NSTimeInterval, queue: dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_get_main_queue(), block: dispatch_block_t) {
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), queue, block)
}
```